# finding list of years and no. of events occurred each year using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

the data set details are:

> id,event,year,rating,duration
>
> 1,f1,1980,3.4,4200
>
> 2,f2,1960,4.2,7273
>
> 3,f3,1980,2.1,2721
>
> 4,f4,1960,3.5,7212
>
> 5,f5,1960,2.1,7786

how can you find the list of years and no. of events occurred each year?

I have tried this but i doesn't work it shows schema error

```
events = load 'event' using pigstorage ',' as (id:int, event:chararray, year:int, rating:float, duration:int);

list_of_years = group events by year;

no_of_events = foreach list_of_years generate count(moviename);

dump no._of_events;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

Firstly, your load statement is incorrect:

*events = load 'event' using **pigstorage ','** as (id:int, event:chararray, year:int, rating:float, duration:int);*  -- INCORRECT

PigStorage is a function, the correct way of writing it is PigStorage(',')

Now for your problem,

**Input**

1,f1,1980,3.4,4200
2,f2,1960,4.2,7273
3,f3,1980,2.1,2721
4,f4,1960,3.5,7212
5,f5,1960,2.1,7786

***Pig Script***

//Load the data using the correct Syntax and delimiter.

events = load 'stack_case001.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, event:chararray, year:int, rating:float, duration:int);

//Group the data by year

list_of_years = group events by year;

//Count the number of events per year by Iterating over grouped data and counting the number of items corresponding to the grouped entity.

number_of_events_per_year = FOREACH list_of_years GENERATE group,COUNT($1);

//Print the output on screen.

DUMP number_of_events_per_year;

**Output**

(1960,3)

(1980,2)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, in that case don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one with the green tick :)